# PHP Cleaning special characters from string

Tags: php, html, string, parsing

so I made this **scraper** and it returns strings from multiple sites. I want to check if the strings match, so I use php to clean the string and check. However, the `&` and other special characters appear in 2 ways, one as `&amp;` and the other as `&#38;`. How do I go about removing each type.

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $string);
```

I already have that, but that doesn't take out the special characters.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to show &amp as &? or & as &amp?

Comment: one shows it as &amp; and the other as &#38;

Comment: See my answer. You have to use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function removeSpecialChar($string) {
    $string = str_replace('', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}

echo removeSpecialChar(html_entity_decode('&amp;khawer&#38;')); //will output khawer
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. html_entity_decode was what I was looking for. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.

Running your string through this, along with strip_tags() and strip_slashes() should clean up your string.

`htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(strip_slashes($string)));`

Comment: When I run this one of the &#38; becomes &amp;#38;